# how to check if an element that satisfies my conditions is the first one of a kind inside its container?

Tags: jquery

Consider this markup:

```
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="container">
<div>
<div data-attr="color">blue</div>
<div data-attr="color">red</div><!-- this is the only n-th child div to be red -->
<div data-attr="color">red</div>
<div data-attr="color">red</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="container">
<div>
<div data-attr="color">blue</div>
<div data-attr="color">red</div><!-- this is the only n-th child div to be red -->
<div data-attr="color">red</div>
<div data-attr="color">red</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.click').click(function () {
            $('.container div').each(function (i) {
                if ($(this).attr('data-attr') == "color" && $(this).html() == "red" && $(this).prevUntil('.container').filter(function (i) {
                    return $(this).attr('data-attr') == "color" && $(this).html() == "red"
                }).length == 0) {
                    $(this).css('color', 'red');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

That is, I want matching element to be red only if it's first. My problem is I'm restricted to use a script of another structure, so only `ThisIsFirstInsideItsClosestParentContainer` part within `if()` must be rewritten, and the rest part of this script must stay intact.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.click').click(function () {
            $('div').filter(function (i) {
                return $(this).attr('data-attr') == "color" && $(this).html() == "red"
            }).each(function (i) {
                if (ThisIsFirstInsideItsClosestParentContainer) {
                    $(this).css('color', 'red');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Besides, I strongly dislike the use of prevUntil() in my case, but I haven't found another way. So, what's that `ThisIsFirstInsideItsClosestParentContainer` should look like, without using prevUntil()?

**EDIT**
Please, tell my why this doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click').click(function () {
        $('.container [data-attr]').filter(function (i) {
            return $(this).attr('data-attr') == "color" && $(this).html() == "red"
        }).each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).index() == 0) {
                $(this).css('color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="container">
<div>
<div data-attr="color">blue</div>
<div data-attr="color">red</div><!-- this is the only n-th child div to be red -->
<div data-attr="color">red</div>
<div data-attr="color">red</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="container">
<div>
<div data-attr="color">blue</div>
<div data-attr="color">red</div><!-- this is the only n-th child div to be red -->
<div data-attr="color">red</div>
<div data-attr="color">red</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be more readable if you break up things in blocks. Assign all your conditions to variables and make `if` statement shorter and more obvious. I get lost when I've to scroll sideways and keep remembering why is this here and having to look back.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5Ps5C/

Comment: @undefined `if ($(this)...is(this))`? Cool, works, maybe looks too unusual. :) Why did you choose `closest`, not `parents`?

Comment: @lyricallywicked Yes, this is result of using filter for all of the div elements on the page :), you can replace `closest` with `parent()`.

Comment: Hey, what's going on down there???!!! I've seen a 3rd working answer and where's it now???

Comment: Have you tried to use the .index() function in jQuery? If you just call .index() on an element. It will give you a zero-based index number based on it's siblings in the nearest parent element. So, you can test if ($(this).index() == 0)

Answer (score 1):

try this  **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/prY8Q/2/)**

```
$('.click').click(function () {
   $('.container div[data-attr="color"]:contains("red")').first().css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: I've noticed the structure of a script must stay intact. Anyway, thanks, I'll try to make use of this one too

Comment: @lyricallywicked well accepting that answer would be nice if it helped you. Otherwise people will stop to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).is($(this).parent().find('div:first'))){
```